# How can New Relic keep my Java site up?

Tags: java, heroku, newrelic, jhipster, newrelic-platform

Is it possible to use New Relic on my Java site? I built it with JHipster Yeoman generator and deployed the WAR file to Heroku. I setup New Relic. I looked at the default policy. It appears to have a pinging service, but I am wondering if I have to do something in addition to keep my site up. Maybe create a route for the pinging service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the Jhipster site, it says it creates a Spring boot backend:  https://jhipster.github.io/

Providing the version of spring used is v3 or v4 it should work. (I was unable to verify what version boot actually uses)
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/getting-started/new-relic-java

This looks like it should work to me, trying it is the only way to know for sure. Here is the heroku-newrelic-java install doc:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java-installation-and-configuration

The ping service will attempt to connect to your site over http/https from external locations, to verify that it can be reached. You shouldn't need to do any additional configuration on your site.